# ios/swift - force keyboard to stay up with uitextview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextview

Say I have a messaging app on an iPhone, and every time I send a message clicking the "Send" button, I don't want the keyboard to "hide", I want it to stay where it is. Is there any way to do this? I've tried using `textViewShouldEndEditing` to adjust it, but even when it returns `false`, the keyboard still hides. I've also tried using `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` in the `textViewShouldEndEditing` function, but I'm not sure where to put it. Please help, thanks!

Comment: can you show your code a little bit ?

Comment: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textView.delegate = self;
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{return No;}
```

Comment: It is good tone on Stack Overflow to include some text **describing** the code in the answer post. At least you may prepend the code with "This code should work:". But it is better to describe **key features** of the code you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it! I put the `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` inside of the send button's IBOutlet instead of the `textViewShouldEndEditing` function.